# Set focus after an alert message in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to set the focus in a input after an alert box appear. I have problem to set the focus on my field, ref.

My code is simple:

**Javascript**

```
var toFix = true;
$( "#add" ).click(function(e) {
    if(toFix){
        if (confirm('Not valid')) $( "#ref" ).focus();
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<input class="input-text submit" type="submit" id="add" name="submit" value="Add" style="text-align: center"/>    
<input class="input-text" type="text" name="ref" id="ref">
```

**EDIT:**
[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Cu74c/)

Comment: what's the `confirm` for?

Comment: To send a message. I tried deleting the second focus instruction and still doesn't work.

Comment: Works fine for me... http://jsfiddle.net/dirtyd77/WcMBW/

Comment: Not for me. I'm using google chrome.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a `confirm`:

```
var toFix = true;

$( "#add" ).click(function(e) {
    if(toFix){
        alert("fix it"); 
        $( "#ref" ).focus();
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/stevemarvell/fEmfa/

Comment: But still the focus is not going to the input, ref.

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: I'm using chrome and it's fine.

Comment: It seems, it could be a problem with my browser. I tried in my office and works well.

Answer (score 0):

Working code at [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/jtcTA/).
Just remove `if(tofix)`.

Comment: The logic associated with the `confirm` still makes no sense.

Comment: Which is there to represent the validation maybe?

Comment: @stevemarvell He maybe using it for some confirmation checking in original project, anyway it doesn't matter.